# erro no servidor node.js (ejs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js, ejs

ola

tenho esse codigo:

```js
router.post('/loginCli', function(req, res, next) {
  var j;
  conn.query('SELECT * FROM bdlabella.tbclientes order by email_cli', (err, results) => {


    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    }
    // valida se o email ja existe no banco.
    var dados = results;
    dados.forEach(function(row){
      if(row.email_cli == req.body.email_cli){
        loginCli.render(req, res, "Usuario ja cadastrado com esse email!");
      } else if(req.body.senha_cli != req.body.Csenha_cli){//valida se as senha == confirmar senha
        loginCli.render(req, res, "Senha nao compativel");
      } else {
        loginCli.save(req.body).then(results =>{
          loginCli.render(req, res, null, "Cadastro realizado com sucesso!");
          break;
        }).catch(err=>{          
          loginCli.render(req, res, err);
        });
      }

    });


  });

});
```

E ele esta com esse erro na hora de salvar no banco

```js
POST /loginCli 200 150.578 ms - 4375
GET /css/bootstrap.css 304 1.845 ms - -
GET /css/estilo.css 304 6.180 ms - -
GET /engine0/style.css 304 0.842 ms - -
GET /js/main.js 304 1.798 ms - -
GET /engine0/jquery.js 304 2.988 ms - -
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node ./bin/www`
  labelle:server Listening on port 3000 +0ms

C:\E. S\laBelle\routes\index.js:68
          break;
          ^^^^^

SyntaxError: Illegal break statement
    at process.nextTick (C:\E. S\laBelle\node_modules\mysql2\lib\commands\query.js:72:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:9)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Falando que não pode usar o `break`, só que se eu não usar ele e vai salvar no banco o numero de vezes referente aos registros que já tem lá
por exemplo tem 2 registros, ele vai lá e salva a mesma coisa 2 vezes.

Comment: Qual é a idea de ter `break;` no código? O que queres que esse `break;` faça?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não deixou muito claro o seu objetivo com o seu código, olhando ele esta me parecendo que você quer verificar se o `email` já esta cadastrado na DataBase(*DB*) e se não estiver cadastrar.

Porem seu problema não me parece ser o `break` e sim a ideia e implementação que você esta fazendo desse objetivo.

#### Essa parece ser a sua ideia inicial, olhando seu código:

1. Fazer uma `query` no seu DB que retorna todos os registros.
2. Com esses dados fazer um `forEach` para verificar se o email informado esta cadastrado.

   - Se o email **não** esta cadastrado, **cadastra**.
   - Se o email **esta** cadastrado, **não cadastra**.

#### O problema com sua ideia/implementação

No `foreach` cada vez que você verificar um registro que não é um email cadastrado ele vai cadastrar o email.
Aparentemente você notou isso e achou que um `break` iria resolver, porem se o primeiro email retornado pela sua query não for o email informado ele vai cadastrar.

Resumindo: Pegar todos os registros da DB para fazer a checagem de 1 por 1 é um gasto de processamento desnecessário e executar o cadastrar dentro do `forEach` vai gerar uma serie de problemas.

#### Preciso fazer a checagem de 1 por 1 usando `forEach`

Agora digamos que você precise fazer a checagem 1 a 1, por algum motivo, a melhor forma de fazer isso funcionar é retirar a criação do usuário de dentro do `forEach`, usar o `forEach` apenas para ver se ele encontra algum usuário, se **não encontrar** cadastra, ficando +/- assim:

```
router.post('/loginCli', function(req, res, next) {
var j;
conn.query('SELECT * FROM bdlabella.tbclientes order by email_cli', (err, results) => {

    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }

    var dados = results,
        usuario_encontrado = false;
    /// ; ^ inicializa dizendo que não encontrou usuário

    dados.forEach(function(row){
      if(row.email_cli == req.body.email_cli){
          usuario_encontrado = true;   
    /// ; marca como encontrado ^
      }
    });

    if( usuario_encontrado )
    {
        /// usuário já registrado
    }
    else
    {
        /// usuário não esta registrado
    }


  });

});
```

#### Uma solução mais simples

1. Faça uma `query` no seu DB **buscando pelo `email`** informado.

   - Se a `query` **não retornar** registro **cadastra**.
   - Se a `query` **retornar** algum registro **não cadastra**.

Um possível start point:

```
router.post('/loginCli', function(req, res, next) {

    /// ; Você pode verificar se a senha repetida esta certa
    /// ; antes mesmo de fazer a query afinal não faz sentido 
    /// ; fazer nada se isso estiver diferente. 
    if(req.body.senha_cli != req.body.Csenha_cli) {

        return;
    }

    var query = "SELECT * FROM bdlabella.tbclientes WHERE email_cli = ? ORDER BY email_cli",
    /// ;            será preenchido pelo mysql com o valor informado ^ 
        where = [ req.body.email_cli ];
    /// ;                  ^ valor informado

    conn.query( query, where, (err, results) => {

        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }

        if( results && results.length > 0 )
        {
            /// email já cadastrado
        }
        else
        {
            /// fazer o cadastro
        }
    });
});
```

---

#### Sobre o `break` dentro do `forEach`

O `break` não funciona dentro do `forEach`, para parar o ciclo você pode utilizar uma checagem com `return` ou fazer o `forEach` dentro de um bloco `try`/`catch` e disparar uma exceção com o [`throw`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw), veja o exemplo abaixo:

```js
try{
  [1,2,3,4,5,6].forEach( x=> {
      if( x > 2 ) throw "Termina";
      /// ;        ^ dispara a exception
      console.log(x);
  });
}catch(e){}
/// ;  ^ captura a exception para não travar o codigo

console.log("FIM");
```

Referencia: [Node.js MySQL Where](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mysql_where.asp)

Answer (score 0):

O problema está em usar o `break` dentro do `forEach`. Se você quer interromper o loop sem iterar sobre todos os elementos do array, o ideal seria usar simplesmente um `for`. Nesse caso seria possível interromper o loop facilmente com `break` ou `return`.

Referência: http://sajanmaharjan.com.np/2016/08/12/javascript-break-foreach/